# non-sharing vertices still showing same paint when one area is colored

Tags: uv, faces, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I have two islands on my UV map where they look like they could be sharing vertices when zoomed out, but when zoomed in are not in fact sharing any vertices/edges:

[image]

[image]

These are two completely different places on my actual object. Despite the fact that they are not touching, when I texture paint the area on my 3d object which corresponds to a face on one island, the edge closest to that on the other island gets painted as well. Why is this, and how do I fix this?